# CSS Flexbox not aligning textbox with button?

Tags: css, asp.net, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Trying learn and apply some flexbox to a page with some Bootstrap 4 using SCSS. I've tried several combinations but can't get the texbox and button to align horizontally together.

This is the SCSS and HTML I'm trying but the textbox and button stack on top of each other.

```
<div class="impersonate__conatiner">
    <div class="impersonate__item">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImpersonateUserId, new { @class = "form-control impersonate__item", @placeholder = "Employee ID", @maxlength = "8", autofocus = "autofocus" })
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Impersonate</button>
    </div>        
</div>


.impersonate{
    &__container{
        display: flex;
    }

    &__item{
        flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
}
```

If I put something similar in Code Pen it seems to work. This is what I have in Code Pen.

```
<div class="impersonate__conatiner">
    <div class="impersonate__item">
       <input id="search" type="search" placeholder="text"/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Impersonate</button>
    </div>        
</div>

.impersonate__container{
        display: flex;
    }

.impersonate__item{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Any suggestions so I don't have to resort back to a table.